# How to remove Hotspot profile from ElementaryOS network settings

Tags: wifi, networking

A few weeks ago i was messing around with creating a Hotspot but after testing it i didn't want to have it anymore, now every time my laptop starts it automatic login to the test Hotspot i created, i then have to open up Network Settings and disabled the Hotspot option and then my system automatically logins to my home network, This is what i want to happen at startup not to login to Hotspot. I dont see any option to remove this hotspot i created, is there anyway to remove this hotspot via the gui or command line?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the network icon in the top bar and select Network Settings (at the bottom of the menu).

Click on the Edit Connections button at the bottom of the Network window.

In the new dialog, scroll down until you see the hotspot you created and click on it.

The Delete button should then become active, click on that and you will be asked to confirm you want to delete the connection.

After confirmation the hotspot should be removed.

Comment: Hi @rdanter i followed your steps and i didn't see the hotspot name, i already had looked, that's why i'm puzzled.

Comment: Hmm, odd, what do you have in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` ? Is there a file with the same name as the hotspot or one containing a line `id=<hotspot name>` ? If so then you can try to remove it (you will need to use `sudo`).

Answer (score 1):

Also encountered this quirk in `elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera`. There is no `Forget this network` style option for quick removal. It has to be removed manually.

The `terminal`-based method, as per the follow-up comment by rdanter and the [manual removal procedure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284018/is-there-a-way-to-make-ubuntu-forget-a-network-connection) in Debian is:

`cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`
`sudo rm WIFINEWTORK`

This solves the issue in my situation as well.